# How to not re-initialise child component when parent property changes?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm working on a application with a wall like Facebook, with posts components (which have a counter of likes) and nested comments components which are loaded on demand with a button inside the post. I'm using NgRx Store, and I have an unexpected behavior when I follow these steps:

- I open the comments with a button in the post button provided for the purpose, they load correctly
- I click on the like button, then a `LikePost` action is thrown
- Then a `LikePostSuccess` action is triggered, with the new post object (with the number of likes updated) as a payload. Then the likes counter is updated.
- But the issue is: when the `post.likesCount` property is updated, then the child `CommentsComponent` is re-initialized (whereas no data has changed inside) and it makes the display flick.

How it's implemented and what I tried so far:

- I'm using `@ngrx/entity` and two different reducers to manage Posts and Comments.
- In `PostsComponent`, I set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`
- I noticed that this behavior happens when the state is entirely changed in a immutable way (by using `adapter.UpdateOne()` method), but if I just change directly the property `post.likesCount` in a mutable way, it solves the problem, but it's a bad practice.
- I tried to display this `likesCount` in the component with an Observable got from a selector made for this purpose (`likesCount$(post) | async as likesCount`). Then I thought the reference of the data would not move and there would be no child initialization, but it does not work.

**posts.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div>{{ post.title }}</div>

    <button (click)="likePost(post)">
        <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
        <span>{{ post.likesCount }}</span>
    </button>

    <button (click)="toggleComments(post)">
        <mat-icon>chat_bubble</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="comments$(post) | async as comments">
            <app-comments [comments]="comments" [postId]="post.id"></app-comments>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

**comments.component.html**

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">{{ comment.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

**posts.reducer.ts**

```js
const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

  // ...

  on(postsActions.likePostSuccess, (state, props) => {
    const update: Update<Post> = {
      id: props.post.id,
      changes: {
        likesCount: props.post.likesCount
      }
    };
    return postsAdapter.updateOne(update, state);
  })

  // ...
);
```

**posts.component.ts**

```js
// ...

comments$(post: Post): Observable<UserComment[]> {
  return this.store.pipe(select(selectCommentsByPostId(post.id)));
}

// ...
```

Finally, the question is: how to update parent component properties without triggering children initialization? Here the issue is isolated, but I can't imagine what would happen if I had many nested components.

Is the issue comes from ChangeDetection? From the way the store State is updated (mutable/immutable)? Is the using of `@ngrx/entity` library a good choice?

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you post that comments$(post) function

Comment: you should try `trackBy` to avoid creating the element - https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: @user2216584 That worked! Thanks a lot! Please add this comment as an answer and I will tag it as "accepted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `trackBy` in the *ngFor in order to force Angular to keep the same reference of the object, so that it does not need to re-initialize it.

Comment: This comment helped me with something I've been trying to solve for 3 days, god bless you man

Answer (score 0):

As I well see you update posts which you then iterate over, and inside that iteration, you just create a new child component and that's why your child component is reinitialized.